# Which Angular 2 modules are needed for my application?

Tags: angular

I added `@Input` to my Angular 2 directive and I get an error that leads me to believe that I have not imported the Angular 2 module that includes the `@Input` metadata.

```
zone.js:1263 GET http://localhost:8880/vendor/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js/src/metadata/directives.js 404 (Not Found)
```

The proof of this is that when I remove the @Input metadata, the application does not generate any errors.

Within the module that I am using the `@Input` metadata I am importing the `{Input}` from `@angular/core/src/metadata/directives` my IDE (IDEA 2016.2) automatically added the reference for me.

So I need to import the proper Angular 2 module via `@NgModule` - but I'm at a loss as to how to determine what it's called or where its located.

Here's my `ApplicationModule` (bootstrap) module definition:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {BrowserModule, Title} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {UtilityModule} from '../utility/module';
import {I18NModule} from '../i18n/module';

import {FrameworkModule} from '../framework/module';

import {ApplicationComponent} from './application.component';
import {applicationRouting, applicationRoutingProviders} from './application.routing';

import {SandboxComponent} from './sandbox.screen/sandbox.component';
import {SpreadsheetComponent} from './spreadsheet.screen/spreadsheet.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule, UtilityModule, I18NModule, applicationRouting, FrameworkModule],
    providers: [Title, applicationRoutingProviders],
    declarations: [ApplicationComponent, SandboxComponent, SpreadsheetComponent],
    bootstrap: [ApplicationComponent]
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

And here's my `FrameworkModule` in which I am try to use `@Input`:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {TUT_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTIVES} from './directives/index';
import {TUT_FRAMEWORK_COMPONENTS} from './components/index';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    providers: [],
    declarations: [TUT_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTIVES, TUT_FRAMEWORK_COMPONENTS],
    exports: [TUT_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTIVES, TUT_FRAMEWORK_COMPONENTS]
})
export class FrameworkModule {}
```

Presumably I need to add an Angular 2 module import to one of these files to provide the implementation of `@Input`

In general where is the list of Angular 2 provided modules and how can I determine which ones correspond to which features of Angular 2?

**Further Research**

From the Angular website (API documentation):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/

*@angular/core*

`Input`

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Input-interface.html

exported from *@angular/core/index*, defined in *@angular/core/src/metadata/directives.ts*

I'm not sure how to interpret any of the above information in regard to what I need to include in my bootstrap module definition... (maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree)

Comment: The list of all the angular modules you currently have are in your package.json

Can you show what you have in that file?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question--you want to know where to import Input from.
Generally you can find where a particular directive or object lives on the [angular website](http://angular.io) . In your case, input lives in angular/core so you'd write `import { Input } from @angular/core;`

Comment: Which version of angular2 are you using?

Comment: The list of Angular 2 packages that I've loaded onto my development system is in my package.json file - I may or may not decide to use any of these within my application (e.g. I added them to my package.json in anticipation of needing them later, but have not yet referenced one or more of these)

Comment: I am using @angular 2.0.0

Comment: @GabrieleB-David - agreed - this is what I would expect - but I have been unable to find the correct link - what I'm looking for is a simple list of Angular 2 features with a reference to the corresponding module to `import` into my bootstrap module for my application.

Comment: @Neoheurist I opened an issue on Github to request an official list of all the modules provided by the Angular API. Here's the [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12036). We'll see what happens!

Comment: @GabrieleB-David - the response to the Github issue that you logged was provided a link to the [Angular 2 API index](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/) which lists Dircetives, Pipes, Decorators, Classes, Functions, Enums, Interfaces, and Constants by their Angular Module - this addresses my question but in a backwards manner - my preference would be that the definition of an API "feature" provided a "backlink" to its Angular Module and/or an example import statement... and therefore I've logged a documentation feature request to provide this...

Answer (score 1):

To use `@Input()` in your component, you will have to import `Input` from core package like this-

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
```

Reference: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

See if this helps.

Comment: I augmented my original post to clarify that it is not the `import` within my directive that I believe is missing - it's how to import the right Angular 2 module within a Module definition file... thanks for pointing out that I was unclear in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem:

Within my directive my IDE helpfully imported `Input` with it's full path:

```
import {Input} from '@angular/core/src/metadata/directives';
```

The release versions of Angular 2 provide bundles and in my `system.config.js` file I am referencing these as in this snippet:

```
System.config(
    {
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'vendor/'
        },
        // tell the SystemJS loader where to look for packages and components
        map: {
            'application': '.',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',

...
```

because my import included an *extended* path to `Input` the system loader was appending it to the reference in my `System.config` `map:` entry... resulting in a bad path to load the Angular 2 core module `(404)`:

```
zone.js:1263 GET http://localhost:8880/vendor/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js/src/metadata/directives.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Note the `/src/metadata/directives.js` appended to the `core.umd.js` bundle reference...

To fix my problem all I needed to do was to reference the `core` module instead of the `typings` file in which the `export` for `Input` is declared (as follows):

```
import {Input} from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: While I have solved my problem, I still have the question that I initially posed in this post - how does one backtrack from an Angular 2 feature to the appropriate Angular 2 module...